# How to reconnect known project to TFS 2010 with lost mapping

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010, tfs-2008

I recently migrated a .NET 3.5 project to .NET 4 and now want to add the converted project to a TFS 10 server while keeping the original intact on a TFS 08 server because we also need to maintain the current 3.5 project since some customers still use it.

I'm having a problem disconnecting the solution's source control the TFS 08 so that I can add it to TFS 10. I've tried several ways, including some suggested here, without success. VS 10 doesn't allow me to switch servers while selecting a different location in the process of adding it to source control. I've also tried removing all mapping because it somehow still knows where the solution comes from. I even tried following "How to permanently remove TFS Source Control association bindings?" at http://zayko.net/post/How-to-permanently-remove-TFS-Source-Control-association-bindings.aspx and the son-of-gunner still knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the migrated .NET4 solution in a local path that is not contained in any mapping to a workspace of you TFS2008.
Then, in addition to the points mentioned in your linked article, navigate to "File" >> "Source Control" >> "Change source control..." and proceed to Unbind all the projects from your old Server. Save all with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and close VS.
Open another instance of VS & connect your Team Explorer to TFS2010. Open Solution (it should now be treated as completely uncontrolled) and navigate to "File" >> "Source Control" >> "Add Solution to Source Control...". This should open up a dialog that lets you choose where (in the TFS2010 repository) you 'd like your .NET4 solution to be placed.